# PHP array_push multidimensional associative array to maintain structure

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array :

```
 $array= array(
        'Book1' => array('http://www.google.com', '45' ),
        'Book2' => array('http://www.yahoo.com', '46',
        'Book3' => array('http://www.excite.com', '47', )
```

and am trying to write a function where you can search and return  an array with the $keys and $values intact. So if someone where to search "'Book1' , 'Book2' then they would get back an array :

`$results = array( 'Book1' => array('http://www.google.com', '45' ),
         'Book2' => array('http://www.yahoo.com', '46',))`

This:

```
$bookArray = array()
$bookDetailsarray = array();

$needles  = array('book1' , 'book2' ); 

   foreach ($needles as $needle) {

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) 
        { 

            if ($key == $needle) 
                { 
                array_push($BookArray, $key);
                array_push($bookDetailsarray, $value);
                array_push($bookArray, $bookDetailsarray);                                                          
                }             
        }
     }


  }
```

This works, but on each iteration of the foreach it keeps adding the $bookDetailsaray to the $value. So it returns:

```
Book1 => [0]'Book1details' 
Book2 => [0]'Book1details' [1]'Book2details'
Book3 => [0]'Book1details' [1]'Book2details' [2] 'Book3details'
```

and so on.

I want to be able to do:

```
array_push($BookArray, $key=>$value);
```

but obviously thats not possible. 
Any ideas? Even if its just what array function I need .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly more efficient method to do your search using basic PHP functions rather than looping:

```
$searchArray = array( 'Book1' => array('http://www.google.com', '45' ),
                      'Book2' => array('http://www.yahoo.com', '46'),
                      'Book3' => array('http://www.excite.com', '47' )
                    );

$needles = array('Book1','Book3');

$searchResults = array_intersect_key($searchArray,array_flip($needles));

var_dump($searchResults);
```

But note that it is case-sensitive

**EDIT**

If you wanted a case-insensitive search, you could use [array_intersect_ukey()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-ukey.php) instead, using a custom comparison to ignore the case of the keys.

```
function key_compare_func($key1, $key2) {
    $key1 = strtoupper($key1);
    $key2 = strtoupper($key2);

    if ($key1 == $key2)
        return 0;
    else if ($key1) > $key2)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

$searchResults = array_intersect_ukey($searchArray, array_flip($needles), 'key_compare_func');
```

**EDIT 2**

Using [strcasecmp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) can make the user-defined key comparison a lot simpler too.

```
function key_compare_func($key1, $key2) {
    return strcasecmp($key1,$key2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic instead (although, I am not 100% what you want the last line to do?)

```
$BookArray[]=$key;
$bookDetailsarray[]=$value;
$bookArray[]=$bookDetailsarray;
```